# RoR : form.select + onchange not passing the right value in params to the controller

Tags: jquery, select, controller, action, parameters

I have a select menu in a Ruby on Rails form defined as follows:

```
<%= f.select :Menu1, [["Option1","value1"],["Option2","value2"]], {}, {:id=>"Menu1_Id", :class => "Menu1_Class"} %>
```

I am using an event handler to trigger controller action when an option is selected and I want to pass to it the value of the selected option

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src=http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
$(function(){
    $('.Menu1_Class').bind('change', function(){
        alert($(this).val());
        $.ajax('#{:controller => "TestsController", :action => "show"}?param_one='+$(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
```

EDIT : this is the js code that worked for me thanks to Robin's answer below (notice I'm using it for action "get_results" instead of the original one "show"):

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(function(){
  $('.menu_class').bind('change', function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "<%= get_results_my_tests_url %>",
        data: {
          param_one: $(this).val()
        }
      });
    });
});
</script>
```

in my controller

```
# GET /tests/1
# GET /tests/1.json
def show
  @test = Test.find(params[:id])
  if params[:param_one].present?
    @blah=params[:param_one]
    puts "show : @blah = " + @blah.to_s + "\n"
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @test }
  end
end
```

With this, the alert message contains the right value (value1 or value2) but param_one is not present so puts returns nothing for "param_one", while I expect to see "value1" or "value2" there.

Anyone can please point me to where am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your javascript to the following:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src=http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
    $(function(){
        $('.Menu1_Class').bind('change', function(){
            alert($(this).val());
            $.ajax({
                url: "<%= test_path(@test) %>",
                data: { param_one: $(this).val() }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```