# ruby on rails jquery not calling the right controller action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, routes

I read all the answers that popped up when I started posting this question but they don't seem to solve my issue.

I added a new action called get_results to my controller (in addition to the ones that were created via scaffolding), but every time I change the choice in the select menu, it directs me to "edit" action, not "get_results",

This is the js

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(function(){
  $('.menu_class').bind('change', function(){
      $.ajax('#{:controller => "my_tests", :action => "get_results"}?param_one=' + $(this).val());
  });
});
</script>
```

EDIT : this is the js code that worked for me, THANKS to Robin's answer below:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(function(){
  $('.menu_class').bind('change', function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "<%= get_results_my_tests_url %>",
      data: {
        param_one: $(this).val()
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

This is the action I added (snippets)

```
def get_results

  # some stuff goes here

  respond_to do |format|
    if @my_test.update_attributes(params[:my_test])
      format.html
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :action => "update" }
      format.json { render :json => @my_test.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I added a specific route for it into my routes.rb

```
MyTests::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :my_tests
  get "home/index"
  match '/my_tests/get_results' => 'my_tests#get_results', :as => :get_results
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
  root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

EDIT : this is the routes config that worked for me, THANKS to Robin's answer below:

```
resources :my_tests do
  collection do
    get :get_results
  end
end
```

rake routes gives me this

```
my_tests     GET    /my_tests(.:format)                    {:action=>"index", :controller=>"my_tests"}
             POST   /my_tests(.:format)                    {:action=>"create", :controller=>"my_tests"}
new_my_test  GET    /my_tests/new(.:format)                {:action=>"new", :controller=>"my_tests"}
edit_my_test GET    /my_tests/:id/edit(.:format)           {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"my_tests"}
my_test      GET    /my_tests/:id(.:format)                {:action=>"show", :controller=>"my_tests"}
             PUT    /my_tests/:id(.:format)                {:action=>"update", :controller=>"my_tests"}
             DELETE /my_tests/:id(.:format)                {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"my_tests"}
home_index   GET    /home/index(.:format)                  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"home"}
get_results         /my_tests/get_results(.:format)        {:action=>"get_results", :controller=>"my_tests"}
                    /:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))
      root          /                                      {:action=>"index", :controller=>"home"}
```

So why is it always directing me to "edit" action and not "get_results"?

Comment: Without any errors? I'd expect it to try to use "get_results" as the ID since your match is after the "resources" routing. Any reason you didn't add a RESTful action? Also, please tag the question with an appropriate rails version tag.

Comment: Nope. if I point my browser to my_tests/get_results, then I get this error "Couldn't find MyTest with id=get_results"

This is the trace I see on the server

Started GET "/my_tests/11/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Jan 01 15:20:54 -0800 2012
  Processing by MyTestsController#edit as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"11"}
  MyTest Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "my_tests".* FROM "my_tests" WHERE "my_tests"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "11"]]
Rendered my_tests/_form.html.erb (9824.6ms)
Rendered my_tests/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (9828.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9847ms (Views: 9843.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)

Comment: See an [earlier answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8694347/438992), this is the same problem. When you get an error, you should include it in the question.

Comment: @Dave: thanks for the pointer. I changed it to   resources :my_tests do
    get 'get_results', :on => :collection
  end
and commented the match line but still no luck;-(

Comment: Update the question with current code. Did you fix the JS?

Comment: @Dave : I updated my code with "EDIT" prefix ; thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

Your javascript should be

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(function(){
         $('.menu_class').bind('change', function(){
             $.ajax({
               url: "<%= get_results_my_tests_url %>",
               data: {
                   param_one: $(this).val()
               }
             });
         });
     });
</script>
```

Your routes:

```
resources :my_tests do
    # if "/my_tests/get_results" is really what you want
    collection do
        get :get_results
    end
    #if "/my_tests/1/get_results" is what you actually want
    #it would make more sense, especially because you have @my_test in the controller
    member do
        get :get_results
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Robin. You saved my day! your suggestions worked perfectly after I fixed a minor syntax error in the js code url: "<%= get_results_my_tests_url %>"(my_tests instead of tests and there is a "," a the end of url: line)

Comment: Actually, you also fixed my other issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692353/ror-form-select-onchange-not-passing-the-right-value-in-params-to-the-contro ; I can give you credit for it if you reply to it

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax('#{:controller => "my_tests", :action => "get_results"}?param_one=' + $(this).val());
```

Since there is no ERB in that snippet, the above will just be a normal string in JS. It will construct a url like:

```
http://example.com/the_current_page#{:controller => "my_tests", :action => ....
```

and the part of the URL after the `#` won't get sent to the server. Take a look at it in the network panel and it should be clear what's happening.